# Protobuf message from JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers, grpc-web

In python/C#/C/Go/... generated code it is possible to create a proto message instance from JSON. E.g. [in Python](https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/json_format.html) where you can just do `google.protobuf.json_format.Parse(json, message)`. I would expect the [JavaScript generated code ([here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/master/js) and [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/javascript-generated#any)) to offer the same, but unfortunately this is not the case.

I am currently sending my JSON in a `Struct` and receiving the same back. So now I want to upack that `Struct` and get the message back. But I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

You actually have a library called [protobuf.js](https://github.com/protobufjs/protobuf.js) and you can try it out with `ObjectInformationType.fromObject(JSON.parse(msg))`.

It parses the JSON object into protobuf.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, but than I would have to combine both the Google JS library and protobuf.js. Not sure how that would work.